# Best NoSQL-way to store machinedata?

Tags: c++, c, database, nosql, berkeley-db

I'm looking for a NoSQL-way to store machinedata like information about tools, work pieces, products, operations and so on... Currently I'm concentrating on BerkeleyDB and need input from you guys, whether I should consider using another nosql-database which might fit better on my requierements. Data stored in this db should be transferable on other machines and the overhead of the API should not ne too big... Maybe there is not that **one** perfect db to manage it, but maybe someone has a good idea how to solve that.

There are some other related questions here, but not directly what I need.

To be a bit more precise: I'm working at a company which builds large grinding machines which are used for manufacturing drills, windings or big hobs. There is much information to store about the tools the machine uses, the products it can grind, like lengths, angles, velocities and so on.

What I need is a non-relational database model which does not offer **TOO** much overhead I do not need... It should be simple and embedded, but fitting for my requirements.

The software which will operate with the db is written in C/C++.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: What operating system do you use? There is less choice on the windows os.

Comment: The software will be running on WinXP and propably Win7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Berkeley db seems to be a good fit for your requirement

Answer (score 1):

Even though it violates your "no sql" theme: I'd say [sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/) is worth a look.  It's compact and efficient.  Not sure about the "embedded" part.  If you're just talking about bundling it in with your app, then yes.  Not sure how well it fits in [embedded systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_system).  I have no reason to believe that BerkelyDB is not also a good choice.